# how to sum results of a calculated column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, calculation

I'm trying to get the total duration of membership types (member&casual) another application of the same problem would be to get the total count of the population and total count of a particular group eg members then use the results to calculate percentage of population that members represent

````
     member_casual
     started_at,
     ended_at,
        ended_at-started_at as duration
from `cyclistic-case-study-349400.2020_q1.4`
group by member_casual = 'member'```

also tried

```select 
     member_casual
     started_at,
     ended_at,
        sum(ended_at-started_at) as duration
from `cyclistic-case-study-349400.2020_q1.4`
where member_casual = 'member'```

any help will be appreciated
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From following query, you can get the duration of each `member_casual`.

```
SELECT member_casual,
       SUM(DATE_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, DAY)) AS duration
  FROM `cyclistic-case-study-349400.2020_q1.4`
 GROUP BY 1
```

For other metrics you mentioned, you need to use a window(analytic) function or need a subquery to get a total population to calculate the percentage.

(update)
I've tried it with a test dataset and got the following output.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_dataset.cyclistic_case_study_349400` 
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  skip_leading_rows = 1,
  field_delimiter = ',',
  uris = ['https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q8d2nwUTGH33MRpWShU-2dMhjYC1JANJ']
);

SELECT member_casual,
       SUM(DATE_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, DAY)) AS duration
  FROM `my_dataset.cyclistic_case_study_349400`
 GROUP BY 1;


+---------------+----------+
| member_casual | duration |
+---------------+----------+
| member        |      137 |
| casual        |      509 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: SUM without Group By will work, like i described in my answer, so the GROUP By is superfluous

Comment: Yes, right. If  only `member` in `member_casual` column is being considered.

Comment: SELECT list expression references column member_casual which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:8]

Comment: Error message shows you are missing `GROUP BY 1` (same as `GROUP BY member_casual`) in your query.  Try it again with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a [date function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=en#date_diff) or [datetime functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions?hl=en#datetime_diff).

depending what information you need day month you will have to choose, which output format you need

```
select 
     member_casual
     started_at,
     ended_at,
        sum(DATE_DIFF(ended_at,started_at, DAY)) as duration
from `cyclistic-case-study-349400.2020_q1.4`
where member_casual = 'member'
```

or

```
select 
     member_casual
     started_at,
     ended_at,
        sum(DATETIME_DIFF(ended_at,started_at, DAY)) as duration
from `cyclistic-case-study-349400.2020_q1.4`
where member_casual = 'member'
```

Comment: i have managed to get durations for each record i want to sum it by select criteria. ie sum of duration for members only

Comment: none of the above work even when i remove the where clause

Comment: the try the date_diff or Datetime_diff and see what error you get